# How do I perform Monte Carlo sampling in NetLogo?

Tags: random, netlogo, sampling, montecarlo, calibration

I'd like to conduct a sensitivity analysis and calibrate my ABM using the Monte Carlo method. I found an R package called RNetlogo that could do it but is outdated. Since I need to obtain the data of the parameters (input) and their corresponding output, setting the parameters in random values in NetLogo wouldn't help.